# adjust wrapper css to follow responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I started my web project trying to follow responsive design rules. To do so, i expressed all dimensions as percentages. Filling my start page with divs and images was fine. My css files starts like

```
body, html {
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

But when my page reached a height a little greater than viewport , it stops expanding anymore and my new additions doesn't show up. I read that height percentage refers to container height and you have to define first parent's height in pixels so that childs can get their heights. I search for a couple days now, reading suggestions about "overflow:hidden" , "height:auto" which by the way doesn't work in my case, using bootstrap and so on but the main question remains: which modifications to the above css provide a wrapper that can be automatically expanded by height when adding new elements in a way to follow responsive design?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried min-height instead of height? It should let you set a height that's at least 100% but that will expand with your content if your content is taller than the viewport.

Comment: Not working. It shrank my header

Comment: It might be worth adding what you're working on to https://jsfiddle.net/ so we can see more clearly what the problem is and offer some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Remove the 100% height. You don't really need it.
2. Add `overflow: scroll;`:

   wrapper {
       position:relative;
       overflow: scroll;
       width:100%;
       height:100%;
   }

Edit to add:

3. Change height to min-height as suggested in comments to the OP.

What's happening in your code is that you're telling the #wrapper div to be as tall as the screen, and no taller.  If it's as tall as the screen, there's nothing to scroll down to; you're seeing the whole thing.  Technically the contents are continuing (overflowing) below the div itself, but it's offscreen.  By setting overflow to scroll, that tells the browser to NOT let it overflow, but scroll instead.  See here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Ultimately, though, I would probably just leave the height off entirely unless I had a really specific reason to include it.

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
#wrapper{
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
```

Edit to add: I think you're going to have to give us some sample code, because the info you're giving us clearly isn't everything we need.  What browser are you using?

This works fine:

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
#wrapper{
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1>Hello There</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum something sumthing fnord. Adipiscing at invidunt et eos ut te exerci possim eirmod vel ipsum lorem kasd. Veniam labore labore vero sit nulla lorem et rebum et voluptua duis clita sit. Tempor enim lorem placerat erat feugiat et ut tempor. Sit delenit gubergren qui vero eirmod tempor facilisis. Sadipscing imperdiet aliquam dolor vero. Nulla aliquyam et dolore sit aliquam vel stet. Amet rebum lobortis amet. Lorem diam eirmod ipsum. Augue dolores sadipscing rebum eos dolor praesent. Takimata justo labore. Voluptua dolore sit luptatum invidunt justo justo diam clita lobortis dolor labore. Te soluta eos dolor sit lorem nostrud accusam luptatum euismod dolore sit. Ipsum veniam imperdiet dolor laoreet consetetur voluptua diam iusto elitr consetetur duo. Est justo elitr facilisis gubergren dolore tincidunt stet dolore et clita tempor sanctus ea. Dolores eum dolore clita erat accusam et eos clita at. Sea sea esse tempor ullamcorper lorem. Sit dolore dolor erat tempor qui elitr gubergren dolor sit. Sea soluta illum sed ipsum zzril erat gubergren.</p>
    <p>Et molestie quis aliquyam sanctus magna takimata lorem et consetetur sadipscing et. Gubergren et dolor tempor ullamcorper eos accusam et justo. Tincidunt dolor velit amet aliquyam sanctus takimata sea duis accusam sed ea et diam et option aliquyam et magna.</p>
    <p>Accusam consetetur sed suscipit amet sit vero in duis clita amet. Et invidunt erat enim invidunt erat lorem duo ut euismod clita. Facilisis illum ut velit sanctus sadipscing diam dolore sadipscing veniam accusam. Kasd lorem sit esse. Invidunt dolor elitr duis ipsum sit sed ipsum dolore justo. No diam sed tincidunt dolore ex aliquyam. Sadipscing lorem adipiscing qui quod dolor lorem lorem veniam accusam et et. Te et amet in. Et vero illum dolores lorem at vero option takimata. Accusam eum eros nonumy at lorem iriure feugait dolor labore duis amet ipsum. Kasd consectetuer kasd diam gubergren autem takimata diam sit dolore praesent et consetetur id erat tation consetetur sadipscing.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope. I added new div with height:50% and black background color so i can check height expand but it doesn't show up at all

Comment: See edit above. Added a code sample. I think you're going to have to give us some sample code, because the info you're giving us clearly isn't everything we need to solve the problem.

Comment: Ohhhh..my god... problem was a missing slash in closing div tag. My apology and thanks for your effort

Comment: When in doubt, validate! ;-)